# How to get text and single-row table to render inline in Ruby Prawn

Tags: ruby, prawn

I want to render some text followed by a few single row tables. If I try the following:

```
pdf.text "Credit Card Number: "
4.times do
  pdf.table [Array.new(4, Prawn::Text::NBSP)]
  pdf.text " "
end
```

...each element ends up on its own line. Is there a simple way to make them render inline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create table with subtables, like this:

```
require 'prawn'

Prawn::Document.generate('ccn.pdf') do |pdf|
  pdf.text "Credit Card Number: "
  tbl = pdf.make_table([Array.new(4, Prawn::Text::NBSP)])
  pdf.table([[ tbl, " ", tbl, " ", tbl, " ", tbl ]],
    :cell_style => { :borders => []} )
end
```